# Is there any Uniswap quote function for on-chain calls?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, exchanges, uniswapv3

I want to expect how much input tokens should be spent to get exact amount of output token on Uniswap V3.
Uniswap V2 has `router.getAmountsIn()` to expect it.
V3 supports quote interface but it is supposed to be called from off-chain only.

If it's impossible, I want rough value too.
So I want to calculate A to get B. In some way, we got rough value A.
A -> B', B' >= B, B'- B -> 0

Comment: hello bro. Did u figured out how to do on chain? please help

Comment: @BirukDamte, I've just posted an [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/156390/66190) to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uniswap has their own on-chain solution for quoting prices now.

https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-view-quoter

Comment: tnx a lot brother

Comment: Do you have an example where this is deployed and in use? Feel like I've only seen v1/v2 quoters in the wild.

Comment: I am not sure if they have a deployed one for product version. Rather I think they are still in staging phase, Anyway they say, the interfaces are same as V2, so for now it'd be better to go with V2 contracts and later we will be able to upgrade easily.

Comment: Any idea how to implement the Quoter? Looks like importing is not viable cause all the files are made for 0.7.6 compiler.

Comment: Why don't you simiply upgrade the version to latest? 
Or Uniswap now provides quote apis, which you could bring the quoted data to on-chain using Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

The formula is laid out in the SDK documentation.  You need to read the slot0 value from the UniswapV3Pool contract of the pair you are interested in.  The first uint160 value returned in the sqrtPrice96X.  Then depending on which token price of the two you want you either use:

price = sqrtRatioX96 ** 2 / 2 ** 192

or

price =  2 ** 192 / sqrtRatioX96 ** 2

https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/v3/guides/fetching-prices